# ¿Para que se utiliza una librería-biblioteca en arduino?

Tags: arduino

Estoy aprendiendo Arduino y me topé con la parte de el uso de librerías, por lo que entendí son herramientas que me pueden ahorrar mucho trabajo, pero quiero aprender un poco mas.

---

¿Alguien sería tan amable de explicarme para qué sirven?

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante realizar preguntas en base a el documento [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), . No olvides realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos.

Comment: Las librerias son código que otros han escrito y que tu puedes reutilizar para no tener que reinventar la rueda. Con C/C++, todo son funciones (`printf`, `digitalWrite`, ...) y cada una de ellas está en una librería. Si no existieran, tendrías que escribir tú el código de impresión, de manejo de archivos, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

efectivamente las librerías son herramientas que te pueden ayudar mucho a la hora de programar. Tienes que verlo como una navaja suiza, sirven para muchas cosas.

Al principio, cuando estás aprendiendo, tienes que ver las librerías como una caja negra. No te aconsejo que entres a ver los códigos que hay detrás porque si no tienes la suficiente experiencia, no vas a entender nada y seguramente te genere frustración.

Para [instalar librerías de Arduino](https://programarfacil.com/blog/arduino-blog/instalar-una-libreria-de-arduino/) tienes 3 métodos:

- A través del gestor de librerías de IDE de [Arduino](https://programarfacil.com/blog/arduino-blog/curso-de-arduino/)
- A través de un archivo zip
- O directamente copiando todos los archivos en la carpeta por defecto de Arduino en tu sistema.

A parte de saber instalar, es importante que sepas cómo elegir la más adecuada para tu proyecto. Lo típico es que esté en [GitHub](https://github.com/). Allí encontrarás cientos de librerías que hacen de todo.

También hay algunas webs dedicadas exclusivamente a librerías de Arduino como [Arduino Libraries](https://www.arduinolibraries.info/).

Bueno Maxi, espero haberte ayudado aunque sea un poco :)